# Can't bind Alienware multimedia key to KDE shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I am trying to create an entry in "Custom Shortcuts" settings in KDE (Ubuntu). I can set the trigger to e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> but the button I'm interested in is the multimedia key which, under Windows, launches the AlienFX software.

All the other media buttons do something. How can I capture this one? I guess its scancode is off the chart, so to speak.

Comment: Which multimedia key exactly would that be? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The one which launches the AlienFX configuration software. In principle, shouldn't there be a way of capturing any unusual extra key?

Comment: You need to configure them first. Actually, are your media keys working in KDE? Do you use them for something?

Comment: The normal keys (play/pause etc) work fine.

Comment: Run `showkey` and see if your key is being recognized by the system.

Comment: showkey gives no output for that key

Comment: Run `dmesg|tail -5` and if when you press the key a line appears with something like "Unknown key pressed", then it has a scancode and it can be mapped.

Comment: No extra ouput in dmesg

Comment: What about `sudo showkey --scancodes`? You have 10sec to press a key, then it quits.

Comment: Nothing for that key. Something for other media keys.

Comment: Try for last `showkey --keycodes`.

Comment: Still nothing for that key.

Comment: In that case, I can't help you further. If there isn't even a scancode, I have no idea how to make the system recognize the key.You should reconsider your shortcut, it will save you a lot of trouble.